# WebP Image Replacement

Tags: javascript, webp

My end goal is to detect if the browser is capable of displaying webp images.  If it is, replace all the images on the page with their webp equivalent (located in the same directory with the same name, just different extension)

Currently I have a script that successfully detects if the browser is able to display webp

```
(function(){
  var WebP=new Image();
  WebP.onload=WebP.onerror=function(){
    if(WebP.height!=2){
      console.log("You do not have WebP support.");
    } else {
      console.log("You do have WebP support.");
    }
};
  WebP.src='data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjoAAABXRUJQVlA4IC4AAACyAgCdASoCAAIALmk0mk0iIiIiIgBoSygABc6WWgAA/veff/0PP8bA//LwYAAA';
        })();
```

Inside the case for having webp support I have tried the following code but been unsuccessful.

```
// replace .gif with .webp
var allImages = document.body.getElementsByTagName("img");
var length = allImages.length;
var i;
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
  allImages[i].src.replace("png", "testtest");
  console.log(allImages[i]);
}
```

When placed in the header the console does correctly show all of the image tags, but the source has not been changed from the filename.png that it originally was.

Any ideas on what is being done incorrectly?

**Edit:** I found found out the problem with why it was not loading the images, thanks to wsanville.  Looking at the network tab in chrome however still reveals that I am loading both the png and now the webp image as well.  How can I prevent the png image from loading in the first place?

Comment: I suggest using a lighter solution for the webp support detection http://stackoverflow.com/a/27232658/288906

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `replace` function **returns a string**, it doesn't mutate it. You just need to assign the value back:

```
allImages[i].src = allImages[i].src.replace("old", "new")
```

**Edited for comment:**
All browsers will download the corresponding file in the `src` attribute of an image. As an alternate to your approach, I suggest storing the file name in a different attribute of the `img` tag.

Your image tags could look like:

```
<img alt="" data-png-source="/path/to/image.png" />
```

The corresponding Javascript could set the `src` attribute to the correct version.

```
var supportsWebP = true; //set this variable properly

for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    var image = allImages[i];
    var pngSource = image.getAttribute('data-png-source');
    image.src = supportsWebP ? pngSource.replace('.png', '.webp') : pngSource;
}
```

Comment: Such a simple bug, I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, looking at the network tab in Chrome, it seems I am still downloading the png image, and then the webp image.  How can I prevent the png image from ever downloading?

Comment: It is working for Chrome now however it does not seem to be properly adding in the src attribute when I try to load it in Firefox.  Putting a console log in the for loop has revealed that the loops isn't even running (For firefox & IE).

Comment: Found the problem. The image loader is only running if the browser did have WebP support. Just had to shuffle things around.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this a very old question, but as I looked for a way to replace webp images with corresponding jpgs, I didn't find much.

With [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315347/webp-image-replacement?rq=1), I put this together which seems to work through IE 9.

(It might actually work further back with an older jQuery version, but I'm using jQuery 2.1.1 which breaks in IE <= 8 so I'm not certain)

It checks for .webp support, then if the browser doesn't support .webp, it replaces all occurrences with a .jpg equivalent.

```
$(function() {
  var WebP=new Image();
  WebP.onload=WebP.onerror=function(){
    if(WebP.height!=2){
      $('img[src$=".webp"]').each(function(index,element) {
        element.src = element.src.replace('.webp','.jpg');
      });
    }
  };
  WebP.src='data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjoAAABXRUJQVlA4IC4AAACyAgCdASoCAAIALmk0mk0iIiIiIgBoSygABc6WWgAA/veff/0PP8bA//LwYAAA';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have (some) control of the server, you can use content negotiation instead of javascript. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html for how it's done in Apache.

Comment: Unfortunately on this server I do not have any control over it.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to solve a variation of the classic responsive image problem.

The problem you have with changing the image src attributes is that a modern browser will look  ahead and start downloading images *with the wrong extension*. You probably don't want to download images you aren't going to use.

The trick is to place the image inside a *noscript* tag, then progressively enhance that by changing the path as you read the *textContent* of the tag. In older browsers you will need a [simple polyfill](https://github.com/jameswestgate/noscript-textcontent) to read out the content of noscript tags.

You can view my series on responsive images and webP support [here](http://queryj.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/responsive-images-whats-the-problem-9-2/). View an example [here](http://opencomponents.com/flexible/) based on Ethan Marcotte's classic responsive design.