# Cross-browser Webp images support

Tags: html, image, webp

I have a problem. In my HTML pages, I have a lot of *Webp* images that I can visualize only using *Google Chrome*. With other browsers like *Mozilla*, *Explore*, and *Safari* I can't see them.

Is there a solution? Maybe without change every image's extension (cause they are a lot)?

Thanks

Comment: Related - [Detecting WebP support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5573096/104380)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to fallback to a supported image format.

Below's example is using the [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element and the [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) elements with an `img` element fallback. The browser will try loading the assets inside the `<picture>` element from top to bottom until all the "conditions were satisfied" (optional `sizes` attribute and complex `srcset` which aren't in the below code) and the content format is supported.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="image.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

---

### If the images are used in CSS:

You can use [Modernizr's](https://modernizr.com) `.no-webp` class name to target non-support browsers and serve a non-webp format instead:

```
.no-webp .elementWithBackgroundImage {
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
```

#### [This article](https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/) has good information you can use

---

#### [Detecting browser WEBP support](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq#how_can_i_detect_browser_support_for_webp) - A guide by Google (creator of WEBP)

Comment: @MarcoP - well, you need 2 formats for sure. You can also use 3rd party image hosting service such as [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/blog/quick_guide_using_webp_on_your_website_or_native_apps), which can auto-detect browser support and serve the right format to the user

Comment: Ok thank you very much, it will be a long work for me ahah