# How to serve a .JPG for browser that not support .webp in a proper way?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, webp

I am planning to use `WebP` on my E-Commerce website.It can boost a performance a lot based on Lighthouse test. But the problem is. we still have user that use iOS which does't have support for `WebP` format. I need more information about the **proper** way to deliver the images also how to let user download the images in JPG.

On my server. I have both formats for fallback purpose.

Comment: `I read some reference` what reference, so we don't just double up on the information you've already *researched*

Comment: **See Also**: [Cross-browser Webp images support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53206746/1366033)

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way to use [picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element. The browser will consider each child  element and choose the best match among them; if no matches are found, the URL of the  element's src attribute is selected.

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/media/examples/surfer-240-200.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img src="/media/examples/painted-hand-298-332.jpg" />
</picture>
```

EDIT:
As per Jaromanda's suggestion, we should look for fallback in img tag itself as internet explorer doesn't support `picture` element.

```
 <img src="image.webp" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='image.png'">
```

if we want to make sure that  browser only downloads one file: a WebP or a fallback image; not both. We can use [data-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes and assign the appropriate source based one browser support but in that we need to check for os/browser upfront.

```
 <img data-jpg="image.jpg" data-webp="image.webp" id="myimg">
```

and in JS

```
let img = document.getElementById('myimg');
 if(supportedBrowser){
   img.src = img.getAttribute('data-webp');
 }else{
   img.src = img.getAttribute('data-jpg');
 }
```

Comment: Also, Internet Exploder will effectively just display the `<img` as it has no clue what to do with `picture` and `source` :p i.e. it won't "consider" anything :p

Comment: True, Also Apple is typically resistant to supporting formats founded by rivals, so in ios devices, even chrome also can't help as it must use Safari engine.

Answer (score 3):

To serve WebP images with HTML elements, you can use `<picture>`

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="path/to/img.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="path/to/img.png">
</picture>
```

If have a large number of pages or too little time to edit HTML code, then Apache's mod_rewrite module can help us automate the process of serving .webp images to supporting browsers. Edit or create if the file doesn't exist  `.htaccess`

```
odule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.webp -f
  RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ %1\.webp [L,T=image/webp,R] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

AddType image/webp .webp
```

For more information [click Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-and-serve-webp-images-to-speed-up-your-website)

Comment: Can .htaccess server a jpg for iOS browser and webp for another browser that supported?

Comment: It depends on browsers and `RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp` condition will check the browser compatibility. When a browser makes a request, it includes a header to indicate to the server what the browser is capable of handling. In the case of WebP, the browser will send an Accept header containing image/webp. We will check if the browser sent that header using RewriteCond, which specifies the criteria that should be matched in order to carry out the RewriteRule.

Comment: Safari will never support WebP imho

Comment: There are already hundreds of JPG images existing on server. Is there any way to convert these images in to .WebP format on server, or do we need to re-upload them? @VineshGoyal

Comment: No, you don't need re-upload images, you can generate WEBP images from JPG with the help of PHP or NODE tools. try https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webp @BhargavJoshi

Comment: @BhargavJoshi even though this is an old question, you can use ImageMagick for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use **[webp-hero](https://unpkg.com/webp-hero@0.0.0-dev.27/dist-cjs/)**: WebP images are displayed also on browser that don't support them. With this method, JPEG images are generated on-the-fly, you don't have to hold your images in both formats on your server!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/webp-hero@0.0.0-dev.27/dist-cjs/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/webp-hero@0.0.0-dev.27/dist-cjs/webp-hero.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    var webpMachine = new webpHero.WebpMachine()
    webpMachine.polyfillDocument()
</script>
</head>
<body>
This WebP image is also visible on Internet Explorer 10 and 11<br><br>
<IMG SRC="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp">
</body>
</html>
```

**Live example**: https://codepen.io/niente0/pen/dyvQQvO

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion:

The redirect rule makes the browser to download both JPG and webp format, which I suppose is not intended. In order to avoid this, the last letter of the redirect rule shoulbe be changed from [R] - redirecto - to [L]

```
RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ %1\.webp [L,T=image/webp,R] 


RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ %1\.webp [L,T=image/webp,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

I just made a custom helper method that is used exactly like the built in image_tag helper, but will fallback to png if webp is not supported by the browser.

```
def image_tag_dynamic(source, options = {})

        options = options.symbolize_keys

        filepath_webp = source + ".webp"
        filepath_png = source + ".png"

        content_tag :picture do
            # the order of the <source> tags determines priority of image format. Browsers not supporting webp will default to png.
            content_tag(:source, srcset: image_path(filepath_webp)) do end + 
            content_tag(:source, srcset: image_path(filepath_png)) do end +
            image_tag(filepath_png, alt: options[:alt], title: options[:title], width: options[:width], height: options[:height], class: options[:clazz])

        end 
    end
```