# How to show webp image in picture tag?

Tags: html, image, tags, webp

What's wrong with this picture tag?

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://media3.giphy.com/media/8FNlmNPDTo2wE/200.webp">
    <source type="video/mp4" srcset="https://media3.giphy.com/media/8FNlmNPDTo2wE/200.mp4">
    <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/8FNlmNPDTo2wE/200.gif" width="356" height="200" alt="me-5sf-fickledavid-8FNlmNPDTo2wE">
</picture>
```

Chrome should pick up the webp image but it always uses img with gif. If I remove the img tag Chrome shows nothing.

This is the pen I made as a demo https://codepen.io/maxim-palenov/pen/oNvarZY.

[image: The screenshot from Chrome]

Comment: Hi there, just wondering if you discovered antything in relation to this? I'm encountering it myself at present and I'm wondering why it is happening?

Comment: **See Also**: [Cross-browser Webp images support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53206746/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in this at all. It is working as expected. In the img tag, it won't replace the webp image.

Here's what you've to do.

- Rename the gif image to something is broken link. Still, it will keep showing the image.
- After above, if you rename the webp image link, now you'll see the image getting broken.