# browser support for next gen image formats

Tags: image, jpeg, webp, jpeg2000, jpeg-xr

google page speed insights says to use next gen image file formats in our web pages to speed up but as we all know these formats such as JPEG 2000, JPEG XR are not supported by majority of the browsers but WebP format is supported by a few  browsers. However I wonder why Google test tells us to do so. can we do a workaround for image format supportability just like we do for different screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google dev docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/webp)

> Lighthouse collects each BMP, JPEG, and PNG image on the page, and then converts each to WebP. Lighthouse omits the image from its report if the potential savings are less than 8KB.

It is also recommended to use fallback other browsers which does not support next gen formats. One such approach is to use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs)  --> [link to Google docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq#how_can_i_detect_browser_support_for_webp)

There is also a  [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573096/detecting-webp-support) with different implementation options