# How to make the browser choose between <video mp4> and <img webp>

Tags: html, image, video, mp4, webp

GIFs are heavy (xx mb), so we convert them to mp4 and webp. How to make the browser choose `<img webp>` or fallback to `<video mp4>` if he does not support webp?

I know we can use `<source>` in one `<video>` or in one `<picture>`, but how to make the browser choose between one `<img webp>` and fallback into `<video mp4>` if needed?

Is there a way to put the webp in the `<video>`? or a mp4 in `<img>`?

Regards

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573096/detecting-webp-support for a detection solution