# How to load one image if sopported or another if not in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have been reworking a web site to optimize for SEO. One thing I did is to optimize Images using Googles Webp Format. But Webp is not supported on any version of Safari.

My question is: What can I do to load one image (Webp) if supported or load another like JPG if not supported.

It could be great if it is something like the Audio or Video TAG

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting WebP support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573096/detecting-webp-support)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46992947/240443).

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-and-serve-webp-images-to-speed-up-your-website#step-5-%E2%80%94-serving-webp-images-to-visitors-using-html-elements

Answer (score 2):

Add your code like as below and it should most probably work.

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="image.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</picture>
```

More details are mentioned here [in this link](https://usefulangle.com/post/114/webp-image-in-html-with-fallback).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using only 1 image in src (in img tag) if that fails to load then you are trying to loan any other image. So, You can use

```
<img src="invalid_link" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='other_image_url';">
```

Hope this helps.