# Fallback for WebP poster in video tag, how?

Tags: video, fallback, webp, poster

```
<video controls poster="image.webp">
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I would use poster in WebP format, how I can make fallback to JPG for browsers that don't support WebP?

Comment: you'd want to use something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232658/1569675- and based on the response choose the WebP or JPG poster

Comment: Hey did you find a solution other than @Offbeatmammal one?