# How to load a webp image for a background-img when the browser allows it and when not load a png?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a header that uses a webp image as background if the browser allows it, but when not I want the browser to load a png instead.

this is the HTML I have

```
<div class="no-webp">
    <section class="section-hero box-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 hero-bg">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="webp">
    <section class="section-hero box-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 hero-bg">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS I have so far:

```
section.section-hero{
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 296px;
}

.webp section.section-hero {
  background-image: url(/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/hero-banner.webp);
}

.no-webp section.section-hero {
  background-image: url(/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/hero-banner.png);
}
```

but I can't figure out how to link everything together, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the browser using [the method explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser). From there, you could check for the browsers that have it or not and add the relevant class to the HTML element in question.

So you would have a different class for each background image. For example:

```
.webp-supported {
  background-image: url(/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/hero-banner.webp);
}

.webp-not-supported {
  background-image: url(/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/hero-banner.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If php is an option I recommend using this:

```
if( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp' ) !== false ) {
   // yeah, webp is supported!
}
```

If you need to do it via JS, then check [this one out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232658/9108282).

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is by using the `<picture>` tag in HTML. This will work in every browser, as browsers which do not support the `picture` tag will just display whatever source is specified in `<img>`. For example:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/hero-banner.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/hero-banner.png" type="image/png"> 
  <img src="/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/hero-banner.png" alt="Hero Banner">
</picture>
```