# <picture> equivalent for fallback from webp to jepg

Tags: html, svg, jpeg, webp, fallback

I have the following classic SVG code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <image 
    xlink:href="foo.webp"
    height="100"
    width="100"
    x="0"
    y="0"
    image-rendering="optimizeQuality"
  />
</svg>
```

However, on some browsers, webp is not yet supported (iOS and macOS I am looking at you: https://caniuse.com/?search=webp) ...

So, is there a way similar to the `<picture>` element to do something like this (syntax obviously wrong, but I hope it does convey the idea):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <image 
    xlink:href="foo.webp"
    height="100"
    width="100"
    x="0"
    y="0"
    image-rendering="optimizeQuality"
  />
  <fallback_to>
  <image 
    xlink:href="foo.jpg"
    height="100"
    width="100"
    x="0"
    y="0"
    image-rendering="optimizeQuality"
  />
</svg>
```

... without of course getting the double-http-hit problem. And without using client-side Javascript (modernizr or other).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject). Inside the element you can specify the HTML that you need, like the `<picture>` element.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400">
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200">
    <picture xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <source srcset="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Johnrogershousemay2020.webp/200px-Johnrogershousemay2020.webp" type="image/webp">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Johnrogershousemay2020.webp/200px-Johnrogershousemay2020.webp.png" alt="logo">
    </picture>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: will try and you guys know, thanks :)

Comment: this seems like it is working - very natural and no client-side or server-side detection, 100% native, so is the chosen answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could [detect WebP support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573096/detecting-webp-support) and hide the relevant `<image>` element based on the results.

Comment: yup... but id prefer to do it server-side. python.

Comment: You detect WebP in the browser, and send support details in the request.  Eg. as a request header or a cookie.

Comment: mmm that is a nice idea, which I will try :)